# Send to ZeroMQ cloud backend with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, sockets, zeromq

I am learning ZeroMQ and making from scratch all the examples in the guide (in NodeJS). But I'm stack with one that creates a local cluster that processes jobs and, if it cannot process anymore, sends the jobs to “cloud peers” connected through other sockets ([“Putting it All Together” example](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Putting-it-All-Together)).

I ask for your help in debugging the code to see **why clients' messages are not processed by cloud peers (and returned)**:

1. When workers connect, send a READY message to let localBE how many there are. This message is PUBlished to all cloud peers (with peer name attached).
2. When a client sends a REQuest, it's received by localFE.
3. LocalFE ROUTEs to localBE if there are local workers available. Otherwise ROUTEs to random cloudBE peers.
4. Suposedly, cloudFE receives that message and ROUTEs to its local workers if available. Then it should return to the original peer's client (¡!)

If you [clone and execute my repo](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/zguide) (`cd` to *Chapter3* and then two terminals with `node peering3.js me you` and `node peering3.js you me` for example), you can follow who sends and receives (`Get`) data.

You can play with `NBR_CLIENTS` and `NBR_WORKERS` (lines 12 & 13) and see that jobs are not properly sent/returned…

If you could take a look to my code I would be very grateful!

Thanks in advance…

Comment: Before diving in to see if I can help, kudos to you for (a) going through the guide and (b) actually working the examples. I highly recommend you submit your code for any examples that are missing a node version.

Comment: Thanks! You'll see things still missing here, but I focused on local-cloud communication before… I'm the first one learning ZeroMQ at work and I wanted to go through the guides before presenting anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your addressing going between cloud brokers.  You're using local `workers` IDs for addressing between cloud brokers.  Code commented to highlight issues.

```
//  - Route any request locally if we can, else to cloud.
localfe.on('message', function() {
    var args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
    console.log('LocalFE: Get  ' + args.toString());

    if (localCapacity > 0) {
        console.log('LocalFE: Send '+ workers.shift() + ',\'\',' + args[0]+ ',\'\','+ args[2] + ' to LocalBE');
        localCapacity--;
        statebe.send(localCapacity);
        localbe.send([workers.shift(), '', args[0], '', args[2]]);
    } else {
        //  Route to random broker peer automatically
        var randomPeer = randomBetween(3, argc);
        var peer = process.argv[randomPeer];

        /////////////////
        // why are you referencing `workers` here, that is only for local workers
        // You correctly route to `peer` here, though, so that should be fine
        // however, you've removed a local worker from the queue erroneously
        /////////////////
        console.log('LocalFE: Send '+ workers.shift() + ',\'\',' + args[0]+ ',\'\','+ args[2] + ' to CloudBE at peer ' + peer);
        cloudbe.send([peer, '', args[0], '', args[2]]);
    }
});
```

... `cloudfe` then correctly routes the message on to a local worker, but it doesn't check for available workers in the `workers` queue before it does so, so if all local workers are taken, then you're borked, the local `workers` queue will be empty and the message won't go anywhere.  You also lose the reference to your cloud peer, so when the message comes back, there's no way to know it needs to go back to the cloud peer:

```
cloudfe.on('message', function() {
    var args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
    console.log('CloudFE: Get  ' + args.toString());

    /////////////////
    // if `workers` is already empty, `shift()`ing it will get you `undefined`
    // also, you're removing the ID from the queue, which causes problems below
    /////////////////
    console.log('CloudFE: Send '+ workers.shift() + ',\'\',' + args[2]+ ',\'\','+ args[4] + ' to LocalBE');
    localCapacity--;
    statebe.send(localCapacity);

    /////////////////
    // you're now sending it to a *different* worker than you logged above
    // and you've removed *two* workers from the queue instead of one
    // as said above, if `workers` is already empty, you'll route it nowhere
    // and lose the message
    // further, nowhere in here are you logging the identity of the cloud peer, so you've 
    // lost the ability to route it back to the cloud peer that has the client
    /////////////////
    localbe.send([workers.shift(), '', args[2], '', args[4]]);
});
```

... the worker should process the message and send it back to its local broker successfully, at least for the first two messages (not 5 since we're only sending it to workers 2 and 4).  But not only did we lose the reference to the cloud broker that sent us the message before, we don't even attempt to send it back when we receive it from the worker:

```
//  Reply from local worker.
localbe.on('message', function() {
    var args = Array.apply(null, arguments);
    //console.log('LocalBE: Get  ' + args.toString());
    workers.push(args[0]); // Add its identity to the array.

    //  We broadcast new capacity messages to other peers.
    localCapacity++;
    statebe.send(localCapacity);

    //  If it's not READY message, route the reply to client.
    if (args[2].toString() != WORKER_READY) {
        console.log('LocalBE: Send ' + args[2].toString() + ',\'\', ' + args[4].toString());

        /////////////////
        // you're attempting to send it directly back to the client, but the client
        // you're addressing is not `connect()`ed to this broker, it's connected to
        // the cloud broker, so it goes nowhere
        /////////////////
        localfe.send([args[2], '', args[4]]);
    }
});
```

So:

1. Don't `shift()` your workers queue when `localfe` sends to the cloud broker - you're likely losing all of your local workers before even getting a chance to send them work
2. At the beginning of receiving a message on `cloudfe`, `shift()` a worker ID off *once* into a local variable and use that local variable wherever you need it
3. Capture your cloud peer ID and add it to the message so that you know which peer originated the cloud request.
4. If there are no available workers in the queue, either hold it and do a `setTimeout()` to try again, or send it out to a new cloud peer.  For the sake of simplicity, I suggest the former, otherwise you have to track potentially a whole train of cloud peer IDs in your message.
5. When receiving a message back from a worker, check for a cloud peer ID and, if found, route it back appropriately rather than blindly routing it back to a client that might be connected through a different cloud broker.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I'll give it a try and let you know if you saved the day! :)

Comment: It works, albeit just one thing crashes Cloud communication: when Server1 sends “_[**Server2**, Server1, Srv1Client, Msg]_” to the Cloud, Server2 receives “_[**Server1**, Server1, Srv1Client, Msg]_”. Thus, I can't say “if this cloud msg is addressed to me, process it”, because Server2 name is gone…

[I duplicated Server2 within envelope to check how it changes.](https://github.com/Miguel-Herrero/zguide/blob/master/Chapter3/peering3.js#L224)

Do you know why the envelope changes its contents when sent?

Comment: [Check this out](http://zeromq.org/tutorials:dealer-and-router) for a full explanation of how routing works with ROUTER/DEALER sockets (XREQ is DEALER, XREP is ROUTER). The `Server2` address is removed because it's redundant - if Server2 received the message, it knows it was addressed to `Server2`, what it needs to know is where it came from, `Server1`. ZMQ manages that on the backend, and the message only tells you what you need to know.